# Facebook like button on password-protected content

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Subscription-based Wordpress site has password-protected content.

Owner wants a "like" button on every page of the protected content, but, as you can imagine, when FB tries to retrieve the URL of the "liked" page it's always directed to a "sign-up" page, which is, of course by design (similar to a person trying to access content without an account).

So, the "like" counts are wrong, and subscribers can only hit "like" once, since FB sees each "like" as the same page.

I've scoured the earth for a solution but can't find one.  Anyone figure a work-around?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your like button would need to be external from the stuff that is liked so that every page has a different like button.

Take, for example, vbulletin boards, which have areas that are member only.

Your website would need to be partly unprotected, protecting only the passworded stuff.